# how exactly can I replace server-sent event with websocket?

Tags: java, websocket, jersey, server-sent-events

I am using Jersey to build a RESTful webservice which using server-sent event heavily. As we all know that IE does not support server-sent event(SSE), for a period of time I thought that I can use websocket rather than SSE(I finally use polyfill actually), but the problem is how can I do that?

One of the solution I came up with was using the websocket endpoint as a jersey client so that I can get the response and convert it into a event and then send it to the real client. 
I know there are many problems out there, for example, not all request result in an event. I can imagine that that websocket endpoint will be very complex and soon out of control if I consider very situation.

Any idea? Thanks.